# How do I prevent requests using the TRACK method on Apache

Tags: apache, pci-compliance

I'm going through a PCI compliance checklist and need to disable HTTP TRACK and TRACE methods on Apache for one PHP website. How can this be done reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know de context, but I've found this:
http://blog.techstacks.com/2008/08/apache-configuration-and-pci-compliance_26.html
good luck!

Comment: Yes, I did discover that blocking those methods in the htaccess file works well.